# How to get values from $form_state with webform

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I'm using webform for submission and trying to simulate
GET parameters (though by default it uses POST).

Here's my code implementing `hook_form_alter()`:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $nid = 2;
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_' . $nid) {
    $option['query'] = array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 
        'email' => $form_state['values']['email'], 
        'gender' => $form_state['values']['gender'], 
        'birthday' => $form_state['values']['birthday'], 
        );
    $form['#action'] = url('path/to/myViewsPage', $option);
  }
```

Above code should take me to

```
'path/to/myViewsPage?name=tom&email=tom@gmail.com&gender=male&birthday=12/21/2013'
```

But I got following error:

> Undefined index: values in mymodule_form_alter()

Could someone tell me where to define the `$form_state['values']`? Isn't it predefined by Webform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form_alter() you should ADD a new submission handler.

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $nid = 2;
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_' . $nid) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'your_submit_handler';
  }
 }
```

In your_submit_handler() these values will be available

```
function your_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $option['query'] = array(
    'name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 
    'email' => $form_state['values']['email'], 
    'gender' => $form_state['values']['gender'], 
    'birthday' => $form_state['values']['birthday'], 
   );
   $url = url('path/to/myViewsPage', $option);// (valid path or whatever)
   $form_state['redirect'] = $url;
}
```

You dont care about the webform node being saved you only need to redirect, right?
This will run alongside with yout default webform submit handler.

Comment: Thank U, this works better than `drupal_goto()`. This has a nicer organizing and help me understand a lot, thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped , also don't forget to accept an answer or vote up for the ones that helped you out! Yeah drupal_goto() and changing $form['#action'] is a bad idea in form-handling in general..

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hackish, but I think it would it be better if you set the path to your View in `$form['#action']` and post the form directly to your View. Then on your Views page you grab the posted values from the form, in a contextual filter if you need that. In that way you also completely bypass the submission handling and nothing is saved.

Comment: Thank you, this also works. I use GET only for the purpose of bookmark-able. On an unrelated subject, is there always a Views implementation that substitutes a customized SQL query?

Comment: I would say mostly, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

```
//  echo"<pre>"; print_r($form_state); die;
/*** here you check all values of webform which is submitted ***/

$fname = $form_state['input']['submitted']['Your_field_ID'];
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. But seems not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Webform has its own hook to access the submit and all. You could use [hook_webform_submission_presave()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7).

> Modify a Webform submission, prior to saving it in the database.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **$node:** The Webform node on which this submission was made.
>
> **$submission:** The Webform submission that is about to be saved to the
>   database.

See [All Webform Module Hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/group/webform_hooks/7).

Comment: I don't want to save the submission data, just a redirection will be fine. Is there a way to prevent data being saved in webform database?

Comment: Use the `hook_webform_submission_presave` hook and empty the form state.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I solved my problem by using `drupal_goto()` which (seems to me) served the purpose of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $form_state = form_state_defaults();
 $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];
 // Get the form from the cache.
 $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
```

or by providing the form id:

credits: [How do I load the $form_state for a form loaded with drupal_get_form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158408/how-do-i-load-the-form-state-for-a-form-loaded-with-drupal-get-form/175884#175884)

```
// Get the form.
$form = drupal_get_form('my_form_id');
// Get the default form state.
$form_state = form_state_defaults();
// Get the form and form state from the cache for the form you just got.
form_get_cache($form['#build_id'], $form_state);
```