# Pre-populate webform default values with hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform (version 4.11 on Drupal 7) that is failing QA test because the javascript validation is not correctly attaching to an empty required form element-- the 'Please fill out this value' tag is going to the top of the screen instead of near the element that failed validation.

So as a work-around, I decided to add a `hook_form_alter` and a new validation callback, to manually perform the validation. I am setting the error messages with `drupal_set_message`.

It turns out that the `$form` and `$form_state` arrays for webforms are apparently different from the typical form. Instead of `$form_state['values']['field_key']`, I found them here: [`$form_state['input']['submitted']['field_key']`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/68153/1441).

However, I can not figure out where each field's `#default_value` key resides in the `$form` array. I would expect it to be `$form['field_key']`, but it's not there.

How can I pre-populate the default value of form elements in a webform with `hook_form_alter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the values here

```
$form['#node']->webform['components']
```

So for the first component, I would change the value like so

```
$form['#node']->webform['components'][1]['value'] = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$form['submitted']['component_name']['#value'] = 'test';
```